# Calculating multiple car prices from a file

Tags: java

My application needs to read a file, which includes a list of cars from different factories, and calculate the prices (by this I mean mean add up their prices).

I suppose my solution is efficient.  Is there any better approach to it?

> ```
> Company Price  other details
> Benz   10000   x ...
> BMW    3000    y ...
> Benz   1000    z ... 
> Toyota 500     w ...
> ```

In this case the result should be

> ```
> Benz 11000
> BMW  3000
> Toyota 500
> ```

**Solution**

```java
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    List<Company> trn = new ArrayList();
    Company t = new Company();

    t.setName("Benz");
    t.setPrice(10000);
    trn.add(t);
    t = null;
    t = new Company();
    t.setName("BMW");
    t.setPrice(3000);
    trn.add(t);
    t = null;
    t = new Company();
    t.setName("Benz");
    t.setPrice(1000);
    trn.add(t);
    t = null;
    t = new Company();
    t.setName("Toyota");
    t.setPrice(500);
    trn.add(t);

    for (Company c : trn) {
        System.err.println(c.toString());
    }
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
    int counter = 0;
    for (Company c : trn) {
        String name = c.getName();
        if (!map.containsKey(name)) {
            counter = 0;
            for (Company com : trn) {
                if (com.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    counter += com.getPrice();
                }
            }
            map.put(name, String.valueOf(counter));
        }
    }
        System.err.println(map.get("Benz"));
        System.err.println(map.get("BMW"));
        System.err.println(map.get("Toyota"));
    }
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> Company{name=Benz, price=10000}
> Company{name=BMW, price=3000}
> Company{name=Benz, price=1000}
> Company{name=Toyota, price=500}
> 11000
> 3000
> 500
> ```

Comment: sorry but I have rollbacked your latest revision as your code has changed significantly. I think it'll be better if you can mark this answered and then ask a new question with the new code...

Comment: @h.j.k. sorry I am newbie the address of new question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57157/sum-of-multiple-values

Comment: It's all right, glad to help, and hope you'll stay! :)

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57157/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArrayList` and `HashMap` declarations are missing type arguments. Assuming if you're developing on Java 7 then all you're missing is just the diamond operator, e.g. `ArrayList<>()`.

```
Company t = new Company();
t.setName("Benz");
t.setPrice(10000);
trn.add(t);
t = null;
t = new Company();
t.setName("BMW");
t.setPrice(3000);
trn.add(t);
t = null;
t = new Company();
t.setName("Benz");
t.setPrice(1000);
trn.add(t);
t = null;
t = new Company();
t.setName("Toyota");
t.setPrice(500);
trn.add(t);
```

This is an odd way of adding four objects into your `List`. Assuming if your `Company` object has the following simple constructor, you should do it as such:

```
trn.add(new Company("Benz", 10000));
trn.add(new Company("BMW", 3000));
trn.add(new Company("Benz", 1000));
trn.add(new Company("Toyota", 500));
```

Instead of a nested `for` loop and skipping entries that already exist in the result `map`, you can consider retrieving the existing calculated sum from the `map`, if any, and add the current price to that. Also, why is `map` created as `Map<String, String>` and not `Map<String, Integer>` or `Map<Company, Integer>`?

One more thing, you can consider putting this particular comparison as a method in your `Company` class: `com.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)`.

Comment: actually I need to change the type of price to BigDecimal to accept the monetary values. Question is updated

Comment: @Jack: Did you just now figure that out?  You've just invalidated this answer by modifying the code greatly.

Comment: @Jamal sorry I am newbie, the address of new question is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57157/sum-of-multiple-values